# Routing error for image assets folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have specified image source in my view as `<img src="assets/grid2Whitepressed.png" />`. The file name is index.html.erb file and is part of billings controller. I am getting routing error for this

```
Started GET "/billings/assets/grid2Whitepressed.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05
 17:33:36 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/billings/assets/grid2Wh
itepressed.png"):
```

I am new to rails so not sure if this needs to explicitly defined in routes file. I checked many posts but nowhere its mentioned that we have to define route for assets too. I checked the application.rb, development.rb file settings and everything is as mentioned on ROR site. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the path your route is starting from is /billing.
Try this:

```
 <img src="../assets/grid2Whitepressed.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/assets/yourimage.png"></img>
```

always give parent directory name for your path.